# switch case to load value of img src

Tags: javascript

Hello all I am trying to test a case

```
switch(condition){
case 1:dom.byId("showImage").value = "../img/working.png";
break;
default: alert("nothing met");
}
```

Keep in mind I have quite a few images to load dependent on condition would a function such as be more efficient?

```
function(imgValue){

}
```

?

UPDATE:

I have different 10 images that I need to load dependent on condition. Better said my question should be if a "case" matches how would I display it on an id called "showImage" I hope this clears it up a bit. The second part of the question was would a function where all I have to do if a case matches is insert the url to the image more effective? case:grabImage('../img/working.png')

Comment: How would you use a function to replace this switch? You could put the switch inside a function, or use if statements instead.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here or what the question is.  Can you try to explain it a bit more?

Comment: Say you did pull the code out into a new function, you'd still need some logic and any logic you can put here you can put into its own function.

Comment: Are you asking if a function would be better to use than a switch/case?

Comment: I have different 10 images that I need to load dependent on condition. Better said my question should be if a "case" matches how would I display it on an id called "showImage" I hope this clears it up a bit. The second part of the question was would a function where all I have to do if a case matches is insert the url to the image more effective? case:grabImage('../img/working.png');

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what your update lists as your actual question:

```
document.getElementById('showImage').src = "yourpicture.png";
```

Comment: Thanks Marc,

So I tried:
`
         switch(condition){
          case 1:dom.byId('showStateIdImage').src =                        '../img/working.png';
                  break;
             default:alert("not");
     }`
with no results I am sure the condition "1" exists after logging it to console.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dom.byId` syntax.  That's not what I suggested.  And what I suggested is case sensitive.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle that uses javascript to set an `img src` using the syntax I provided: http://jsfiddle.net/rPyCa/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like so...

```
 function getImage(url){
                dom.byId("showCertainImage").src = url;
               //dom.byId is a dojo selector I should have mentioned this sorry                   
             }

   switch(condition){
                case 1: getImage("img/img1.png");//there are 15 others just like this                
                break;
                case 2: getImage("img/img2.png");                
                break;
                default: getImage("img/default.png");
    }
```